# website not working in ie 7

Tags: html, web, internet-explorer-7, ie7.js

When I open my website in IE7 I am getting transferred to the update-browser file. It says "please update browser"

I have tried deleting the update-browser file.

I also tried copying and pasting the index file into the the update-browser file. None of this works. please help!

Comment: Is there some reason you *need* to use ie7 in general?

Comment: some of the companies clients use ie7. I asked my manager the same question.

Comment: What do you mean by delete the update-browser file ?

Comment: there is an html file called update-browser for browswers that don't support the website.

Answer (score 0):

In the ie.js folder I found a browser compatibility check that directed ie 7 to the update browser file. I changed the ie to work < ie 5.

Thanks for everyones input.